# I can't install Skype on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: apt, 14.04, skype, aptitude

I've tried lots of tutorials I found online, but I can't install Skype.

apt-get gives me this error: (but Synaptic doesn't report any broken packages)

```
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Aptitude gives me this error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbusmenu-qt2:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{ab} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{ab} 
  libdrm-radeon1:i386{ab} libdrm2:i386{ab} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{ab} 
  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{ab} libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} libqt4-opengl:i386{a} 
  libqtwebkit4:i386{a} skype skype-bin:i386{a} sni-qt:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 57 not upgraded.
Need to get 31,7 MB of archives. After unpacking 111 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdrm-intel1 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1:i386 (!= 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 2.4.52-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-intel1 (!= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 10.3.0~git20140530.ebf229a4-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.3.0~git20140530.ebf229a4-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
 libdrm-radeon1 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (!= 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 2.4.52-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-radeon1 (!= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 10.3.0~git20140530.ebf229a4-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Breaks: libglapi-mesa (!= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.3.0~git20140530.ebf229a4-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 10.3.0~git20140530.ebf229a4-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 is to be installed.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 10.1.0-4ubuntu5) but 10.3.0~git20140530.ebf229a4-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
 libdrm-nouveau2 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (!= 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 2.4.52-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm-nouveau2 (!= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
 libdrm2 : Breaks: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty) but 2.4.52-1 is to be installed.
 libdrm2:i386 : Breaks: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.52-1) but 2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:          
1)      libdrm-intel1:i386 [Not Installed]                           
2)      libdrm-nouveau2:i386 [Not Installed]                         
3)      libdrm-radeon1:i386 [Not Installed]                          
4)      libdrm2:i386 [Not Installed]                                 
5)      libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [Not Installed]                         
6)      libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [Not Installed]                         
7)      libglapi-mesa:i386 [Not Installed]                           
8)      libqt4-opengl:i386 [Not Installed]                           
9)      libqtwebkit4:i386 [Not Installed]                            
10)     skype [Not Installed]                                        
11)     skype-bin:i386 [Not Installed]                               

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                   
12)     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 recommends libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

And none of the solutions work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you trying to install skype by apt-get, or download?

Comment: I've tried apt, aptitude , download. Seems to be a problem with my sistem tho' . I'm getting the same errors when i try to install wine

Comment: Try the following commands: `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: do `sudo apt-get update` before you do what Tim says to fully upgraded your system.

Comment: is your issue solved now

Answer (score 3):

Based on the version numbers, you're most likely using the [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) PPA (or at least using the packages from that PPA).

In theory, `apt` should get both the amd64 and i386 versions if you have that PPA added. To find out if you have the PPA added, run `apt-cache policy libdrm-intel1`. If the entry with the version number `2.4.54+git20140523.8fc62ca8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty` doesn't have a link to the PPA (there's **only** `100 /var/lib/dpkg/status` and not `500` something), then you aren't using the PPA.

If you aren't using the PPA (even if you aren't using the PPA and want to get rid of the packages safely), run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and then `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

If you don't want to use the PPA (and want to get rid of the packages from the PPA), or you are using the PPA and can't install Skype, run `sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers`.

After following this, try installing Skype.

Comment: you're the best!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue yesterday.  What a pain.  Yep, the pain was me.

Here is how I resolved it:

```
dpkg --add-architechture i386
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install skype
```

Comment: Nice! this helped me when everything else failed. Thanks a lot! By the way I was running a persistent live USB version of Ubuntu 14.04. Hope this helps others too